# ERROR: Unable to locate element

Tags: xpath, selenium, css-selectors

I have to test a dynamic app using the ZK framework and Selenium does not identify the id's from the different elements, so can't enter text in the textboxes or select an element in a list (elements from a database)

Whatever I use (xpath or css selector) nothing works, always the same error

Does anyone know how can I fix my problems?

I'm using Selenium IDE 1.9.0

Netbeans IDE 7.1.1

And Firefox 16.0.2

Thanks

The Html code is:

```
button id="zc_subdossierzulButton_8" class="butt z-button-os" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: #ED0000;" type="button">Rechercher
```

And the Java code i tried is:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("zc_subdossierzulButton_8.butt"));
```

don't work

this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("butt z-button-os"));
```

don't work

and this:

```
String cssSelector = "[class='butt z-button-os']"; 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).clear(); 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).sendKeys("c");
```

Comment: ERROR: Unalb eto locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[class='butt z-button-os']"}

Comment: You can try to figure out a common pattern in the dynamic ids and then play around with xpath/css to form a locator.  You would have to paste some html for anyone to help you figure out.

Comment: i tried this:

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("zc_subdossierzulButton_8.butt"));

don't work
this:
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("butt z-button-os"));
don't work
and this:
String cssSelector = "[class='butt z-button-os']";
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).sendKeys("c");

Comment: please show your html code to make things more clear..

Comment: <button id="zc_subdossierzulButton_8" class="butt z-button-os" style="border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: #ED0000;" type="button">Rechercher</button>

Comment: Your By.cssSelector should be #zc_subdossierzulButton_8 with # in the front, as it is an id.

Comment: always unable to locate element

Comment: Try to downgrade to Firefox 13.0.1.

Comment: Please edit your question to include code instead of posting them in comments where it is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the following documentation and try using different options like

```
driver.findElement(By.id("coolestWidgetEvah"));
OR
driver.findElements(By.className("cheese"));
OR
driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
OR
driver.findElement(By.name("cheese"));
OR
driver.findElement(By.linkText("cheese"));
OR
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("cheese"));
OR
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input"));
```

> http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#locating-ui-elements-webelements